The problem with getting static files in Vercel
I've been racking my brain for a week now why I have this problem. I have a client side (React) and a server side (Express) of my site. When publishing my server part on Vercel, everything works fine for me, authorization works, news is uploaded. But only the storage of static files along the path does not work (example) https://my-site.vercel.app/uploads/image.png. And I don't understand why, because everything else works well.
My index.js file:
import multer from "multer";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import {
  registerValidation,
  loginValidation,
  postValidation,
} from "./validations.js";
import { checkAuth, handleValidationErrors } from "./utils/index.js";
import { UserController, PostController } from "./Controllers/index.js";

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://catosrak:******@test.qt168zu.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=test"
  )
  .then(() => console.log("DB ok"))
  .catch((err) => console.log("DB error", err));

const app = express();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (_, __, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads");
  },
  filename: (_, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage,
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://new.i-m-z.ru",
  })
);
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

app.post(
  "/auth/register",
  registerValidation,
  handleValidationErrors,
  UserController.register
);
app.post(
  "/auth/login",
  loginValidation,
  handleValidationErrors,
  UserController.login
);
app.get(
  "/auth/authme",
  checkAuth,
  handleValidationErrors,
  UserController.authme
);
app.get("/posts/", PostController.getAll);
app.get("/posts/:id", checkAuth, PostController.getOne);
app.post("/posts/", checkAuth, postValidation, PostController.createPost);
app.delete("/posts/:id", checkAuth, PostController.removePost);
app.patch("/posts/:id", checkAuth, postValidation, PostController.updatePost);
app.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    url: `uploads/${req.file.originalname}`,
  });
});

app.listen(3131, function () {
  console.log("Server OK");
    });

My vercel.json:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}

I tried to change vercel.json, tried to upload the project using the CLI, or just importing the project from github.com . But it doesn't work. When trying to navigate the path https://my-site.vercel.app/uploads/image.png I am getting a 404 NOT FOUND error. Although if I deploy my project on my computer to the path localhost:3131/uploads/image.png, I get this image. So, what could be the problem, I still don't understand
My folder:
